# how to combine the objective arrays have the save same key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
var saperatedIngredients =  [{
    ingredients: (2) ['Aar maach', 'Fish fillet']
    searchfilter: "marine fish"
    },
    {ingredients: ['Active dry yeast']
    searchfilter: "yeast"
    },
    {ingredients: (5) ['Ajwain', 'Cumin powder', 'Tamarind', 'Tamarind paste', 'Tamarind water']
    searchfilter: "miscellaneous derived edible product of plant origin"
    }
   ]
```

**but i want the output like this**

```
const IngredientsArray = ['Aar maach', 'Fish fillet', 'Active dry yeast','Ajwain', 'Cumin powder', 'Tamarind', 'Tamarind paste', 'Tamarind water']
```

anyone help me out for this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `flatMap()`

```js
var saperatedIngredients =  [{
    ingredients:  ['Aar maach', 'Fish fillet'],
    searchfilter: "marine fish"
    },
    {ingredients: ['Active dry yeast'],
    searchfilter: "yeast"
    },
    {ingredients:  ['Ajwain', 'Cumin powder', 'Tamarind', 'Tamarind paste', 'Tamarind water'],
    searchfilter: "miscellaneous derived edible product of plant origin"
    }
   ]
 
const res = saperatedIngredients.flatMap(x => x.ingredients);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: hoo this is too good man i just thought it have some logic but you nailed it with simple and neat code thanks man i really satisfied by your anwser

Comment: @SRINIVASACHARYSUTHOJU Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied by answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `reduce`:

```
const ingredients = saperatedIngredients.reduce( (acc, item) => {
 acc.push(...item.ingredients)
 return acc
}, [])
```